# Поиск подобных (related) записей MySQL

Tags: mysql

Имеем 3 таблицы:

1. Таблица компаний (300,000 записей).
2. Таблица категорий (1000 записей).
3. Таблица отношений компания-категория (700,000 записей).

Задача построения "подобных" компаний, компаний у которых схожие категории упирается в то, что в некоторых категориях есть до 7000 вхождений и когда мы пытаемся строить пересечения, то выходит join таблицы к самой себе с миллиардами записей.

Вот такой вот запрос используется для построения компаний, похожих на данную

```
select b.companyid, count(*) from company_categories a join company_categories
b on a.categoryid=b.categoryid where a.companyid=1 group by b.companyid 
order by count(*) desc limit 10;
```

Это запрос для одной компании, если хотим построить для всех за один запрос, тогда в результате SELF JOIN получится большая временная таблица.

Подскажите как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: Если формализовать в объектную плоскость то у вас есть `СУЩНОСТИ` , с некоторым набором `СВОЙСТВ`  , типа ЯБЛОКО => КРАСНОЕ , КРУПНОЕ . И вы остальные сущности пытаетесь прогнать через эту призму , типа если у СУЩНОСТИ есть свойство КРУПНОЕ , то вы к нему клеите КРАСНОЕ ? хочу понять алгоритм .

Comment: **то выходит join таблицы к самой себе с миллиардами записей** Это вы какой `join` используете? `left join` пробовали с `Таблица отношений компания-категория`

Comment: добавил запрос собственно, который и крутим